# Where does window.maximize function gone in selenium 2.30.0?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Today I downloaded **selenium-java 2.30.0.zip** from [seleniumhq.org](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).But on replacing the old jars from new ones in my workspace I found that **driver.manage.window.maximize() function is giving compilation error**.On checking further I found that the desired function is missing.

Can anybody please let me know whether this function has been removed or it has been moved to some other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still there, so you have a problem of your system (maybe a mismatch of jars?)...

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java

(line 782)

Comment: @Abhi_Mishra did you get it sorted?

Comment: Yes that was a problem at my end only.I cleaned the complete project and set it up freshly from beginning and it get sorted.Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Use Manage().Window not Manage.Window